# What's the difference between "FWIW" and "IMHO"?

Tags: differences

What exactly is the difference between FWIW and IMHO?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- *In my humble opinion* (IMHO) underlines that the following is your personal opinion (as opposed, for example, to facts or to your company’s official position on an issue).
- *For what it's worth* (FWIW) is a disclaimer that your contribution to the debate might be considered marginal, i.e. that it may not address the heart of the problem, but you still find it has some applicability.

---

In short: **no**, they are not equivalent.

Comment: They do not mean the same thing.  That is what the __no__ that F'x added to his answer means.  Study the definitions above to see how they differ.

Comment: @mgkrebbs: yes, I should have been clearer

Comment: No, not the same. IMHO means "I think," and FWIW means "I have no idea but..."

Comment: @The Raven: Actually, that is not correct either. F'x's definition is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

FTR:

Note that IMHO tends slightly to END a sentence, whereas FWIW tends slightly to BEGIN a sentence.

For example, that sentence could have "FWIW:" at the beginning of it.

On the other hand, that sentence could have IMO at the end of it.

Just FYI.